# Is there anyway to download a particular file/folder at a certain path in an Azure VM(Windows)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage-account

Is there anyway to download a particular file/folder at a certain path in an Azure VM(Windows), if there is a way pls share the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Run Commands" which basically executes powershell script on the box:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).